# trying to internationalize title and description of an adf-widget in Angular (Blur Admin)

Tags: javascript, angularjs

is it possible to translate title and description of an adf-wiget?

i've tried something like this, but it did not work:

```
angular.module('adf.widget.myWidget', ['adf.provider'])
  .config(function(dashboardProvider, $filter){
    dashboardProvider
      .widget('myWidget', {
        title: $filter('translate')('MYWIDGET.NAME'),               
        description: $filter('translate')('MYWIDGET.DESCRIPTION'), 
        templateUrl: '{widgetsPath}/myWidget/src/view.html',
        controller: 'myWidgetCtrl',
        edit: {
          templateUrl: '{widgetsPath}/myWidget/src/edit.html'
        }
      });
  })
  .Controller [...]
```

or is there a way to update those informations in a controller using the $filter?

Thanks a lot

// EDIT:

I've tried an other solution, but it still wont work:

```
angular.module('adf.widget.myWidget', ['adf.provider'])
  .config(function(dashboardProvider){
    function getName($filter) { var dcName = $filter('translate')('MYWIDGET.NAME'); return dcName; };
    dashboardProvider
      .widget('myWidget', {
        title: getName(),
        description: 'test',
        templateUrl: '{widgetsPath}/myWidget/src/view.html',
        controller: 'myWidgetCtrl',
        edit: {
          templateUrl: '{widgetsPath}/myWidget/src/edit.html'
        }
      });
  })
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this issue by translating the values in custom templates.

```
dashboardProvider.customWidgetTemplatePath('src/...pathToTemplate')
```

I'am also using custom templates for all edit-templates like editTemplateUrl etc.

(Deleted the duplicated question..)

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example of how to use the resolve block

```
angular.module('adf.widget.myWidget', ['adf.provider'])
  .config(function(dashboardProvider, MYWIDGET){
    dashboardProvider
      .widget('myWidget', { 
        templateUrl: '{widgetsPath}/myWidget/src/view.html',
        controller: 'myWidgetCtrl',
        edit: {
          templateUrl: '{widgetsPath}/myWidget/src/edit.html'
        },
        resolve: {
        description: function ($filter) {
          return $filter('translate')(MYWIDGET.DESCRIPTION)
         },
        name : function ($filter) {
         return $filter('translate')(MYWIDGET.NAME)
        }
         }
      });
  })
```

Then in your controller `myWidgetCtrl`, inject in the translated `name` and `description` values as normal injectables

Comment: hi, thanks. i've got no error, but it wont work... the Name and the description are never shown anymore in the Widget.

Comment: updated my question with an other solution wich wont work ...   .___.

Answer (score 0):

MYWIDGET should be defined as a constant with values for its NAME and DESCRIPTION properties and then injected into the config block, just the way you injected $filter

Take a look at [angular module system](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/angular.Module) to see how to create constants

Comment: MYWIDGET and its values are defined in lang_de-DE.json and lang_en-US.json. i've tried to inject the $filter but if i do this like i showed i'll get this error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module BlurAdmin due to: ... folowing many other errors.

Comment: Also, You cant inject $filter into a config block, angular does not support injecting services into config block. you might try to do that inside a resolve block

Comment: can u show me an example? angular is a lot of new stuff for me. :-)

Comment: i've found this: https://github.com/angular-translate/angular-translate/issues/742 but i dont really understand how to do this